# Problems receiving JSON (not XML) from Tropo API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml

Unfortunately my understanding of cross-origin sharing is incredibly limited, but I am trying to use the Tropo api to create a simple text message based on the instructions for setting up a URL [here](https://github.com/tropo/simpleMessage). I haven't been having much luck. Currently, my AJAX functions gets an XML response back instead of a JSON response and I don't really understand enough to debug it/truly understand what's happening to fix it. I thought that specifying contentType and and dataType would be sufficient to receive JSON, but so far no dice:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: ('https://api.tropo.com/1.0/sessions?action=create&token=[redacted]&to=' + num + '&msg=the+sky+is+falling'),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log( data ); 
    }
  });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In your request, make sure you send the **Accept** header

```
Accept: application/json
```

or set the correct **dataType** expectation with your request

```
dataType: json
```